# History of "Featherstonehaugh"

Tags: etymology, historical-change

How did the surname "Featherstonehaugh" acquire its modern pronunciation /ˈfænʃɔː/, in spite of regular English sound changes?

Comment: Many names ending is augh are pronounced like that: Waugh,

Comment: @Lambie Note that 'Niagrara Falls' is pronounced like 'Niffles'

Comment: @Mitch Mitchie, Mitchie, Mitchie I'm gonna git you. [and for our fellow enthousiasts, that's a joke].

Comment: By comparison, Cholmondely [chummly] & Farquaharson [ferguson or fargason] are much easier to work out. Menzies [mingus] has always stumped me, though.

Comment: @Tetsujin - See [this explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menzies#:~:text=Bray%20in%20Normandy.-,Pronunciation,the%20Scots%20language%20(Men%C8%9Dies).) for Menzies.

Comment: Link to Wikipedia [*The name comes from Featherstonhaugh in Northumberland, from the Old English feðere, 'feather', stān, 'stone', and healh, 'corner'*.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Featherstonhaugh#:~:text=Featherstonhaugh%20%2F%CB%88f%C3%A6n,and%20healh%2C%20'corner'.)

Answer (score 4):

Nick Nicholas, at [Quora](http://quora.com/How-did-the-surname-Featherstonhaugh-get-its-completely-unintuitive-pronunciation/answer/Nick-Nicholas-5), writes

> Not getting an answer online, or in Patrick Hanks’ *The Oxford
> Dictionary of Family Names in Britain and Ireland*.
>
> I do get this from Wells, J. C. (2000), *[Longman Pronunciation
> Dictionary](https://hull-awe.org.uk/index.php?title=Odd_pronunciations_of_proper_names_-_examples)*: Odd pronunciations of proper names – examples: there are
> four recorded pronunciations of Featherstonhaugh:
>
> /ˈfɛð ərst ən hɔː/ (Featherstonhaw)
>
> /ˈfiːst ən heɪ/ (Feestonhay)
>
> /ˈfɛst ən hɔː/ (Festonhaw)
>
> /ˈfæn ʃɔː/ (Fanshaw)
>
> Let’s us out Feestunhay, which is something else going on, presumably
> dialectal. We have fɛðərstənhɔː > ˈfɛstənhɔː , eliding the second
> syllable. So now we need to get from Festonhaw to Fanshaw.
>
> John Gragson’s answer to How did the surname “Featherstonhaugh” get
> its completely unintuitive pronunciation? is pretty damn ingenious,
> and I commend him for it. But there’s one factor it misses. It’s just
> a hint in Hanks’ dictionary, under the entry for Featherstonhaugh:
> “the surname is often pronounced Fanshaw and may have been confused
> with Fanshawe.”
>
> Fanshawe is a distinct, equally old surname, deriving from fane ‘a
> temple or church’ and shaw, ‘a small wood or grove’.
>
> So Festonhaw, which is the recorded shortening of Featherstonhaugh,
> was somehow garbled further to something like Fesnaw or Feshnaw, as
> John argues. And then—rather than appeal to a vowel shift (which seems
> somewhat random) or the phonotactic familiarity of shn vs nsh—we can
> just say that the garbled Feshnaw sounded so similar to the
> preexisting surname Fanshawe, that people just conflated the two
> surnames in speech.
>
> But not in writing. After all, the conflation in pronunciation did not
> entitle any Fanshawes to any Featherstonhaugh estates.
>
> So the absurd pronunciation of Featherstonhaugh as /ˈfænʃɔː/ has a
> really simple explanation. They’re not actually trying to say
> Featherstonhaugh. They’ve switched it to a completely different,
> easier to pronounce surname, and they aren’t admitting it.

So the suggestion is that this is wilful conflation to simplify pronunciation. But it's no more than a suggestion.

Comment: Is it really useful to copy/paste a Quora answer?

Comment: Are you saying that the authority _Wells, J. C. (2000), Longman Pronunciation Dictionary_ isn't a valid reference? Hanks? And as for Nicholas's surmising ... is it wrong to use reasonable suggestions (no matter where they have been posted) with the caveat that they _are_ suggestions? Perilously close to the ad hominem fallacy.

Comment: Thanks for the response!